# Oracle - Merge Statement with INSERT and UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert

I have an existing table called TextData with fields TextId and Text.
In below statement, I am trying to merge(Insert/Update) some records into this table using -

```
MERGE INTO maestro.TEXTDATA T
USING ( 
select N'/Common/UserStatusExpired', N'Expired' from dual
union all select N'/Common/UserStatusPwdExpired', N'Pwd Expired' from dual
) AS Source (Id, Txt) ON (T.TEXTID = Source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TEXT = Source.Txt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TEXTID, TEXT) VALUES(Source.Id, Source.Txt);
```

However, getting this error -

```
missing ON keyword
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing in the Merge statement.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be:

```
MERGE INTO textdata t
USING ( 
    SELECT N'/Common/UserStatusExpired' AS textid, N'Expired' AS text FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL SELECT N'/Common/UserStatusPwdExpired', N'Pwd Expired' FROM DUAL
) s ON (t.textid = s.textid )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET text = s.text
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (textid, text) VALUES(s.textid, s.text);
```

Rationale:

- Oracle does not support `AS` to define table aliases - you need to remove that keyword
- The column names must be defined *within* the subquery

I also aligned the column names between the source and the target table so the query is easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `(Id, Txt)` shouldn't be there as they were.

```
MERGE INTO maestro.TEXTDATA T
USING ( 
    select N'/Common/UserStatusExpired' id, N'Expired' txt from dual
    union all 
    select N'/Common/UserStatusPwdExpired' id, N'Pwd Expired' txt from dual
    ) AS Source  ON (T.TEXTID = Source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE SET TEXT = Source.Txt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
     INSERT (TEXTID, TEXT) VALUES(Source.Id, Source.Txt);
```

Comment: Oracle does not support `AS` to define aliases for derived tables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the "as" clause you've specified. Looks like you want to name your columns in the union'd select lists.

```
MERGE INTO maestro.TEXTDATA T
USING ( 
select N'/Common/UserStatusExpired' id, N'Expired' txt from dual
union all select N'/Common/UserStatusPwdExpired' id, N'Pwd Expired' txt from dual
) source ON (T.TEXTID = Source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET TEXT = Source.Txt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (TEXTID, TEXT) VALUES(Source.Id, Source.Txt)
```

The [railroad diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606) shows there is no such "as" clause.

Comment: The  `USING` subquery needs an alias here.

Answer (score 0):

MERGE INTO maestro.TEXTDATA T
USING (
select N'/Common/UserStatusExpired' id, N'Expired' txt from dual
union all select N'/Common/UserStatusPwdExpired' id, N'Pwd Expired' txt from dual
) source ON (T.TEXTID = Source.Id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TEXT = Source.Txt
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (TEXTID, TEXT) VALUES(Source.Id, Source.Txt)